Looking for a connector family that is both wire-to-wire and wire-to-board
This seems like such a stupid question, but am I correct that there aren't any standard connectors that have both wire-to-boards and wire-to-wire versions? It seems impossible to believe, if only because it means extension cables can't be made, but I can't find what I'm looking for.
I am building a bracelet that I'd like to connect first to a breakout board before going to the controller. The wires that are built into the bracelet are very thin and delicate, and the breakout board is a bit bulky, so I'd like the breakout board to be strapped to the user under their shirt up at their bicep, and so for both strain relief and convenience, I'd like the cables coming out of the bracelet to be disconnectable, and a higher gauge than the ones in the wearable. So I'm looking for a connector type to use on the bracelet. Since I'm using JST SH 4-pin between the breakout and the controller, it would be nice to reuse that type and not buy a pack of 100 new connectors for just this, but the bracelet doesn't have a board, so I'd be looking for a wire-to-wire connector, right? (Trying to solder these things to a wire-to-board socket in defiance of the design seems very kludgey) But I can't find a connector type, JST or not, where the (say) female connector is compatible with a wire-to-wire receptacle and with a wire-to-board socket.

On the contrary, there are plenty of general-purpose connectors that can do wire-to-wire, wire-to-board, and even board-to-board connections.
You mentioned the JST SH, which has a pitch of 1 mm. Let me suggest a connector with a 1 mm pitch that is both wire-to-wire and wire-to-board: the Samtec T1M/ISS1/IST1

PCB header: T1M - https://www.samtec.com/products/t1m
Female plug: ISS1 - https://www.samtec.com/products/iss1
Male plug: IST1 - https://www.samtec.com/products/ist1

If you can go up to 1.25 mm, there are more options, such as the Molex Mini mi II and the Molex PicoBlade.

Consider also making a custom flexible printed circuit (FPC) and mating it to a FFC socket. They are thinner and smaller than any of the crimp connectors you have been considering.
Or, for a very flat solution, design two PFCs and use a dual-beam mezzanine connector (my site) on each PFC.

OP could even go for a FPC with low profile board to board connectors over stiffener on the ends. The fine pitch of FPC can be combined with the very wide selection of Board to board connectors with possibilities of more than the typical 1 or 2 rows of flex connectors

@MrGerber Thank you for the suggestion. With your permission, I will add it to my answer.

Sure! Ten characters
